# Installation Error : JHipster: yarn global add generator-jhipster; Command failed

Tags: jhipster

I run this command

```
yarn global add generator-jhipster
```

but show an Error:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Copy & paste the error code into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have Node installed.

Per their documentation:
Install Node.js from the [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) website (prefer an LTS version)